# Why does the market follow a Fibonacci retracement?

Tags: market-data, market-microstructure

the question is in the title and why is it that the market follows a cycle? By cycle, I mean that the market is going up since 8 years and that we think that, most likely, the market is gonna go trough recession soon?
I might be clear on this, im sorry. 
thank you for the answers

Comment: Don't believe everything you hear... there  are a lot of legends and superstitions on Wall Street...

Answer (score 1):

It may well be just because a lot of other traders follow the idea of Fibonacci retracement.